# Sorting for duplicates by several columns as unique in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I need to find a duplicates in my txt file. The file looks like this:

```
3,3090,21,f,2,3
4,231,22,m,2,3
5,9427,13,f,2,2
6,9942,7,m,2,3
7,6802,33,f,3,2
8,8579,11,f,2,4
9,8598,11,f,2,4
10,16729,23,m,1,1
11,8472,11,f,3,4
12,10976,21,f,3,3
13,2870,21,f,2,3
14,12032,10,f,3,4
15,16999,13,m,2,2
16,570,7,f,2,3
17,8485,11,f,2,4
18,8728,11,f,3,4
19,20861,9,f,2,2
20,19771,34,f,2,2
21,17964,10,f,2,2
```

There are ~30000 lines of this. And now, I need to find duplicates in the second column and save to the the new files without any duplicates. My code is:

```
def dedupe(data):
  d = []
  for l in lines:
      if l[0] in d:
          d[l[0]] += l[:1]
      else:
         d[l[0]] = l[1]
  return d

#m - male
#f - female

data = open('plec.txt', 'r')
save_m = open('plec_m.txt', 'w')
save_f = open('plec_f.txt', 'w')

lines = data.readlines()[1:]

for line in lines:
    gender = line.strip().split(',')[3]
    if gender is 'f':
        dedupe(line)
        save_f.write(line)
    elif gender is 'm':
        dedupe(line)
        save_m.write(line)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plec.py", line 88, in <module>
      dedupe(line)
File "plec.py", line 75, in dedupe
      d[l[0]] = l[1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'
```

EDIT 2018-10-28:
I don't remember what I had to sort in this file, I think that 2nd and 4th column must be unique but I'm not sure now. But I found wrong part in my code and because of it, I rebuilt all of code which is also working.

```
def dedup(my_list, new_file):
    d = list()
    for single_line in my_list:
        if single_line.split(',')[1] not in [i.split(',')[1] for i in d]:
            d.append(single_line)
    print(len(my_list), len(d))
    new_file.writelines(d)


data = open('plec.txt', 'r').readlines()[:1]

males = open('m.txt', 'w')
females = open('f.txt', 'w')

males_list = list()
females_list = list()

for line in data:
    gender = line.split(',')[3]
    if gender == 'm':
        males_list.append(line)
    if gender == 'f':
        females_list.append(line)

dedup(males_list, males)
dedup(females_list, females)
```

Comment: Is this working? If not, what's the problem you're having?

Comment: Looking for duplicates is not working. Saving female to file and male to file is ok. But duplicates looking algorithm is not working.

Comment: What result are you getting then? 'Not working' could mean the file is blank or that it has every line, or that it crashes.

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plec.py", line 88, in <module>
    dedupe(line)
  File "plec.py", line 75, in dedupe
    d[l[0]] = l[1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: OP's `dedupe` function will never work the way he expects unless `d` is global or he calls `dedupe` on all the lines, not line by line. Furthermore, OP doesn't store the results of `dedupe`, i.e. `line = dedupe(line)`.

Comment: So, what should I change? 'Cause I really don't know... I tried much of changes and nothing is working...

Comment: `d` is being evaluated as a list and you're trying to access it with a string, that's the first problem you need to focus on. You probably mean to use a dictionary.

Comment: Also where's the `lines` coming from in the dedupe function? You haven't passed that as a parameter.

Comment: There are not duplicate values in the second column by the way.

Comment: Duplicates is on the rest of file. There is ~30000 lines. And there is duplicates because I know this file.

Comment: I changed all code and now everything is working. Sorry for my low knowledge in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Pandas` to read your input file and remove the duplicates based on any column you want.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from pandas import DataFrame

data =StringIO("""col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
3,3090,21,f,2,3
4,231,22,m,2,3
5,9427,13,f,2,2
6,9942,7,m,2,3
7,6802,33,f,3,2
8,8579,11,f,2,4
9,8598,11,f,2,4
10,16729,23,m,1,1
11,8472,11,f,3,4
12,10976,21,f,3,3
13,2870,21,f,2,3
14,12032,10,f,3,4
15,16999,13,m,2,2
16,570,7,f,2,3
17,8485,11,f,2,4
18,8728,11,f,3,4
19,20861,9,f,2,2
20,19771,34,f,2,2
21,17964,10,f,2,2""")

df = DataFrame.from_csv(data, sep=",", index_col=False)
df.drop_duplicates(subset='col2')
df.to_csv("no_dups.txt", index =  false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
seen = set()
for row in my_filehandle:
    my_2nd_col = row.split(",")[1]
    if my_2nd_col in seen:
       continue
    output_filehandle.write(row)
    seen.add(my_2nd_column)
```

is one very verbose way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

OP, I don't know what's wrong with your code but this solution should fit your requirements, assuming your requirements are:

- Filter the file based on second column
- Store male and female entries in seperate files

Here's the code:

```
with open('plec.txt') as file:
    lines = map(lambda line: line.split(','), file.read().split('\n')) # split the file into lines and the lines by comma
    filtered_lines_male = []
    filtered_lines_female = []
    second_column_set = set()
    for line in lines:
        if(line[1] not in second_column_set):
            second_column_set.add(line[1]) # add to index set
            if(line[3] == 'm'):
                filtered_lines_male.append(line) # add to male list
            else:
                filtered_lines_female.append(line) # add to female list

    filtered_lines_male = '\n'.join([','.join(line) for line in filtered_lines_male]) # apply source formatting
    filtered_lines_female = '\n'.join([','.join(line) for line in filtered_lines_female]) # apply source formatting

    with open('plec_m.txt', 'w') as male_write_file:
        male_write_file.write(filtered_lines_male) # write male entries

    with open('plec_f.txt', 'w') as female_write_file:
        female_write_file.write(filtered_lines_female) # write female entries
```

Please use better variable naming the next time you write code and please make sure your questions are more specific.